# Carbon: Umlaut creates broken array

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Currently I'm trying to create an array with the name of all months automatically with the following helper function:

```
if ( ! function_exists('getMonthsArray'))
{
   function getMonthsArray()
   {
       $monthArray = array();
       setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE.utf8');

       for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
           $dt = \Carbon\Carbon::create(2016, $m, 1, 0, 0, 0)->formatLocalized('%B');

        array_push($monthArray, $dt);
    }

    return $monthArray;
   }
}
```

with the following output:

```
array:12 [
      0 => "Januar"
      1 => "Februar"
      2 => b"März"
      3 => "April"
      4 => "Mai"
      5 => "Juni"
      6 => "Juli"
      7 => "August"
      8 => "September"
      9 => "Oktober"
      10 => "November"
      11 => "Dezember"
    ]
```

As you can see **something** happend next to the value "März" (3rd key). I only can imagine that there are some problems with the umlaut "ä".

Comment: Does the comment in the docs help?  http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization

Comment: I believe this has something to do with multibyte strings and shouldnt be an issue. What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Kkinsey - No :( 

@catis 5.6.16

Comment: @catis Your comment is not the problems fix, but it's the correct answer. If you want to create an answer I'll gonna accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U need to wrap it in utf8_encode function like this:

```
$dt = utf8_encode(\Carbon\Carbon::create(2016, $m, 1, 0, 0, 0)->formatLocalized('%B'));
```